# Spring LDAP Authentication with Embedded LDAP Server

Tags: spring-security, ldap

I am trying to achieve LDAP authentication and DB authorization using spring security framework using the embedded spring LDAP server config. I am getting following error message when try to login :  Result code : (INVALID_CREDENTIALS) invalidCredentials

Issue is : when I use config 1 then login issue comes but if I use config 2 then it works. Request to help :

### Config 1:

```
<security:authentication-manager>       
   <security:authentication-provider ref="ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider"
   class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
            <constructor-arg ref="appLdapServer" />
            <property name="userDnPatterns">
                <list>
                    <value>uid={0},ou=users</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="com.smd.security.UserServiceBean" />
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<security:ldap-server id="appLdapServer" ldif="/WEB-INF/conf/mojo.ldif" root="o=mojo" port="007" />
```

### Config 2:

```
<security:authentication-manager>

 <security:ldap-authentication-provider
    user-search-filter="(uid={0})" user-search-base="ou=users"
    group-search-filter="(uniqueMember={0})" group-search-base="ou=groups"
    group-role-attribute="cn" role-prefix="ROLE_">
 </security:ldap-authentication-provider>

</security:authentication-manager>

<security:ldap-server id="appLdapServer" ldif="/WEB-INF/conf/mojo.ldif" root="o=mojo" port="007" />
```

### LDIF File Snippet:

```
dn: o=mojo
objectClass: organization
objectClass: extensibleObject
objectClass: top
o: mojo

dn: ou=users,o=mojo
objectClass: extensibleObject
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: top
ou: users

dn: cn=John Milton,ou=users,o=mojo
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: top
cn: John Milton
sn: Milton
uid: jmilton
userPassword:: cGFzcw==
```

(Password is pass)

I can see in the LDAP server logs that correct password is being passed.

Thanks for reading this.
Amit

Comment: In the user DN patterns, try providing the distinguished name, not just the relative distinguished name components.

Answer (score 1):

In the first configuration, you are telling the `BindAuthenticator` to use the specific pattern `uid={0}` for the LDAP DN, when in fact it is not constructed from the `uid` attribute at all, but instead uses the common name (`cn=John Milton`).

This differs from the second configuration where you are using a search for users with a particular `uid` attribute.

You should remove the `usedDnsPatterns` from the `BindAuthenticator` configuration and instead configure a search bean, as described in the [reference manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ldap-bean-config):

```
<bean 
  class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
   <constructor-arg ref="appLdapServer"/>
   <property name="userSearch" ref="userSearch" />
</bean>

<bean id="userSearch"
  class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
   <constructor-arg index="0" value="ou=users"/>
   <constructor-arg index="1" value="(uid={0})"/>
   <constructor-arg index="2" ref="appLdapServer" />
</bean>
```